# How to get data from columns of a table in HTML

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<table border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="75%" bordercolor="#000000">

  <tbody><tr bgcolor="mediumblue">
    <td width="20%"><p align="center"><font face="Arial" color="white" size="2"><strong>SUB CODE</strong></font></p></td>
    <td width="26%"><p align="left"><font face="Arial" color="white" size="2"><strong>SUB NAME</strong></font></p></td>
    <td width="13%"><p align="left"><font face="Arial" color="white" size="2"><strong>THEORY</strong></font></p>  </td>
    <td width="10%"><p align="left"><font face="Arial" color="white" size="2"><strong>PRACTICAL</strong></font></p> </td>
    <td width="17%"><p align="left"><font face="Arial" color="white" size="2"><strong>MARKS</strong></font></p></td>
    <td width="14%"><p align="center"><font face="Arial" color="white" size="2"><strong>GRADE</strong></font></p></td>
  </tr>


  <tr bgcolor="#ffffff">
    <td align="middle"><font face="Arial" size="2"> 042</font></td>
    <td align="left"><font face="Arial" size="2">PHYSICS</font></td>
    <td align="left"><font face="Arial" size="2">027</font></td>
    <td align="left"><font face="Arial" size="2">028</font></td>
    <td align="left"><font face="Arial" size="2">055&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
    <td align="middle"><font face="Arial" size="2">D1</font></td>
  </tr>

  <tr bgcolor="#e6e6fa">
    <td align="middle"><font face="Arial" size="2">043</font></td>
    <td align="left"><font face="Arial" size="2">CHEMISTRY</font></td>
    <td align="left"><font face="Arial" size="2">026</font></td>
    <td align="left"><font face="Arial" size="2">029</font></td>
    <td align="left"><font face="Arial" size="2">055&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</font></td>
    <td align="middle"><font face="Arial" size="2">D2</font></td>
  </tr>

  


  <tr bgcolor="mediumblue">
  <td>&nbsp;</td>
  <td colspan="5"><b><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white">Result:&nbsp;&nbsp; XXXX
    <!-- : --> 
    
  </font></b> <b><font face="Arial" size="2" color="white"> &nbsp;</font></b></td>
  </tr>
  
  
</tbody></table>
```

I have the above code snippet which creates a table. I want to extract the `MARkS` from the table and store it in an array.

```
document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].cells[3]
```

gives output as `UNDEFINED`

So how can I do so?

***NOTE: I cannot edit the html of the page.***

Comment: it is very basic level question. I would suggest you to first go with jQuery function like parent, children, sibling, find which can do your job easily. See https://api.jquery.com/children/

Comment: @yogihosting Pretty bad advice. It makes sense to touch jQuery when OP can do it without it.

Comment: getElementsByTagName return an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To access column number 3 you will need only few changes.
First is to add id for a table:

```
<table id="table1" ...>
```

Second changing JavaScript code to:

```
var table1 = document.getElementById("table1")
for(var i = 0; i < table1.rows.length; i++) {
    var cell_value = table.rows[i].cells[3].textContent;
}
```

You can then use `cell_value`

or simply use `document.getElementById("table1").rows[i].cells[j].textContent` and `i` will be your desired row and `j` your column (in this case number `3`):

```
document.getElementById("table1").rows[0].cells[3].textContent
```

To avoid header and footer (if existing in table as `<thead>` or `<tfoot>`) you need to change loop:

```
for(var i = 1; i < table1.rows.length - 1; i++) { ...
```

`i = 1` for the header, `table1.rows.length - 1` for the footer.

If you can not add `id=""` to table, you can try using this JavaScript code:

```
var cell_value = document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0].rows[0].cells[3].textContent;
```

`document.getElementsByTagName("table")[0]` is your table with index `[0]`, so it is first table in the document body, then `rows[0]` means it is first row, and `cells[3]` means it is fourth column, and `textContent` will extract data from the cell for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Close, but you need to exclude header and footer.

Comment: Yes, @dfsq you are right. Thanks. I am editing my answer.

Comment: @KamilWozniak semantically u are not wrong. not all tables have headers and footers

Comment: @JacobGeorge thanks, my answer was ok for the exact case, but now is more complex, let's say if author want to add header or footer, it will be more helpful.

Comment: the footer don't necessarily is at the end of the table it can be after the header. Better use `rows = table1.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr');`

Comment: @jcubic thank you for your help, I've tested your teory by putting `<tfoot>` right after `<thead>` in the code and browser still renders footer rows as the last array element.

Comment: Hey, thanks but the sad part is I cannot edit the HTML so I cannot add an ID to it

Comment: @JoeMcKinzie I've updated answer for you. Now it should work for you. Thanks.

Comment: @KamilWozniak Thanks a lot :D

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("table")
```

returns an array of DOM elements. It will be hard to figure out your table from the array list.

the best way to select a table would be to associate an id with it and use `document.getElementById`

```
<table  id="my-table" border="1" cellpadding="2" cellspacing="0" width="75%" bordercolor="#000000">
```

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById("my-table");
```

Also, you need to specify the rows before the cells to select a particular cell, .i.e, for the first cell

```
document.getElementById("my-table").rows[0].cells[0]
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is work:

```
table.find('tr').each(function (i, el) {
    var $tds = $(this).find('td'),
        productId = $tds.eq(0).text(),
        product = $tds.eq(1).text(),
        Quantity = $tds.eq(2).text();
    // do something with productId, product, Quantity
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put the table and cells to different variables for easier debug.
In this sample you need to define an id name for your table like this `<table id="tbl">`

```
var table = document.getElementByID("tbl");
var d = table.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0],
var r = d.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];
```